Net Core Windows Authentication , Set Roles according to Group Membership, Store Roles As Claims (Maybe as cookie). Share cookie across applications
Here is what I am trying to accomplish , and maybe the mix and match isn't working, but I have had a hard time finding a way to execute the following:
Windows Authentication (AddNegotiate) on an API. After the user is authenticated this way I am retrieving their domain security groups, and then from a dictionary assigning them Role claims based on membership.
I want to be able to share this authenticated session across several other apps that use the API to authenticate, so that the groups query only has to happen once a session times out.
Do I want to do some kind of Cookie implementation to accomplish this? So an application looks, doesn't have authentication, goes to the API where after confirming Windows Groups and Roles issues a cookie based on that membership.
Would probably also have a manual LDAP login elsewhere in the application to Add claims to the current User Identity.
My authentication services. Combination of Cookies and Negotiate, without the NegotateiDefualts on DefaultAuthenticationScheme it prompts a login, and I want that to be an automatic. But then after cookie is set, Cookie should be the authentication.
// Authentication Services
        services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
        services.AddScoped<IUserPreferencesService, UserPreferencesService>();
        services.AddScoped<IDomainUserGroupService, DomainUserGroupService>();

        services.AddDataProtection()
            .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "DataProtectionKeys")))
            .SetApplicationName("AuthenticationAPI")
            .SetDefaultKeyLifetime(TimeSpan.FromDays(90));

        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
            {
                options.Cookie.Name = "AuthCookie";
                options.Cookie.Domain = config["DomainSite"];
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
                options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
                options.Cookie.Path = "/";
            })
            .AddNegotiate();  // For Windows Authentication to retrieve User Groups

The /login is a controller:
// LoginUser with Sign In of Claims based on Role Membership
    [System.Runtime.Versioning.SupportedOSPlatform("windows")]
    [HttpGet("login")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login()
    {
        _logger.LogMessage("Loaded Environment : " + _appConfiguration.EnvrionmentLoaded);

        if (User.Identity is WindowsIdentity windowsIdentity)
        {
            var lastAuthenticated = DateTime.UtcNow;
            var roles = GetRolesFromGroups(windowsIdentity);
            var claims = CreateClaims(windowsIdentity.Name, roles, lastAuthenticated);  

            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "Cookie");
            var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

            var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties()
            {
                IsPersistent = true,
                ExpiresUtc = lastAuthenticated.AddHours(1)   
            };

            await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, principal, authProperties);

            return Ok(new { Message = "User signed in."});
        }
        else
        {
            return Unauthorized();
        }
    }

I have Windows Authentication and Anonymous Authentication set to True. Right now initial claims looks like it only is loading in the claims Windows AUthenitcation comes back with automatically, and is not setting the roles from Login.
How can I cause this to, by default, route to login for the SignIn so the user gets the claims immediatly? What mix of authentications am I doing wrong here?

It would be great if you could share if of your existing steps or relavant code snippet. However, your thought seems correct. To implement Windows Authentication with role-based claims in ASP.NET Core, configure AddNegotiate for Windows Authentication and retrieve the user's domain security groups to map them to roles using a dictionary. Store these roles as claims in an authentication cookie, and configure cookie authentication to share the session across multiple applications by setting appropriate cookie properties.

Additionally, provide a manual LDAP login option to add claims to the user's identity. This setup ensures that group queries occur only once per session and the authenticated session is maintained across multiple applications.

If you try implementing what you have planned so far and face any complexity, feel free to share your issue with reproduciable sample in order to assist you quickly.

@MdFaridUddinKiron
I've edited my post with snippet of my Authentication Services, and the Login controller that retrieves Security Groups and then maps those to roles and claims. I am assuming what I am doing wrong, is some mix of how properties are set on my AddAuthentication service. I do actually have a manual login page, where I want to be able to "add" claims to the current user, but Ill tackle this after I have this part working. Other applications will then call this login, and if the user already has a cookie, doesn't need to repeat the AD lookup until cookie expires.

Thanks for your explanation, so did you able to achieve the way you wanted ? Is that working now?

No, still trying to figure this piece out. Particularly sharing the cookie across applications with the ability to update claims from one application that other applications then update when they see the change to the cookie.

Not sure if its would be helpful but what I have (only works in code, for some reason fails on server) is 2 web sites, the first uses windows authentication (could use this one to create your groups), this site then creates a cookie containing any relevant claims then redirects to another site that is cookie based, where the user is authenticated using the cookie from the win auth site.
My code uses .net core 8
Message me if you think we may be able to help each other
